# How to remove locale in globalize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, globalize

I'm using [globalize/globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) to add model translations.
I have `ru, en` locales and want to remove `en` locale from object, how can I remove?

Tried to remove in such a way, but it removes all object with ru, en locales.

```
Country.with_translations(:en).find(1).destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
country.translations.find_by(locale: :en).destroy
```